# How to trigger if(this.props!==nextProps) in componentwillreceiveprops in Unit Testing?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, if-statement, triggers, react-lifecycle

I am new in Unit Testing for React. I have a question regarding the if statement. I need test the function of componentwillreceiveprops, I know I can use spy = sinon.stub(component.props,"componentwillreceiveprops") method to let spy be called.

But in my component, there is an if statement, such as

```
componentwillreceiveprops(nextProps){
    if(this.props.name!==nextProps.name) {
        this.setState({
            oldstate: newstate
        })
    }
}
```

I can make the `componentWillReceiveProps` function called. If I remove the if statement, the setState function can be called either. But what I have in my component contains a if statement, it is not called when I run the unit testing. Is there any way to make this if statement called? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for my typo, should be: this.setState({
            oldstate: newstate
        }); inside.

Comment: Notice that componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. getDerivedStateFromProps that it's supposed to be replaced with is easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

`componentwillreceiveprops` should be `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Thanks,  it will make if statement called?